# How to Pack Google chrome extension if "Load unpacked extension" is disable

Tags: google-chrome-extension, packaging

i am trying to pack my google chrome extesion. but **Load unpacked extension** option is disabled by the organization system administrator (due to organization security policy).

please help me

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, what is the purpose of packing? Because if you want to send it ti Chrome Web Store - you don't need to pack it - they accepts zip files. In other case you can use on of plenty crx tools. For example cli tool `crx` from npm.

Comment: ah, I realized what you asking. So, basically, you can sign your extension sources and install it via drag'n'drop.

Answer (score 3):

You're using a managed device as you yourself stated that the restriction was set by "organization system adminstrator". They're probably just trying to be cautious. Unfortunately, as stated in this [google forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chromebook-central/dpIBim04Eqw/KhXwUeV1CgAJ) there's no bypassing this as this is out of the API's scope. Contact your administrator and ask for permission to enable the button.